# richimage component src value does not work with uri value

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic11g

When I set uri string value into richimage src property, I can not see the image on application ui.
If I try to paste the value into browser it shows the image

ie: **file:/C:/Users/Dijitaluser/AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper/system11.1.1.6.38.61.92/o.j2ee/drs/IncomingPaperWorkWebApp.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/acme/resource/images/upload_file.png**
As a matter of fact, if i put the image file into the same project as you say **image/thefile.png**, that's ok. But I use distributed resources project and I get the uri by using **resourceBundle**. So this solution is useless for me.
I' m trying to test application on my integrated weblogic server, and this uri which is returned by **resourceBundleHelper**, is already validated by browser. Could you plz give me some suggestions about the issue.

Comment: As a note - your current setup will only work if you are on the local box (C:). Remote users will never be able to see that image because of the path. You must find a way to access the image like http://ApacheServer/FileName.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trasnformed my resources project to web project to use web.xml about defining resources servlet. Then moved my all images in META-INF/adf/images and added into my VisualResourceBundle(extends ListResourceBundle) class. 
It works
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/86-images-from-jar-427953.pdf
hope it helps